child-pipeline stage should skip running when is empty generated-config.yml file
Problem to solve
The child-pipeline stage should run only whenever there are changes in the generate-config.yml file , else if is empty file or no such file then it should be skipped
Configuration
.gitlab-ci.yml file … Below is for testing purpose
  generate-config:
      stage: build
      before_script:
        - apt-get update -y
        - apt-get -y install git zip unzip wget jq apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg python3 > /dev/null 2>&1
      script: python3 python/generate-jobs.py
    
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - generated-config.yml
    
    validate-generated-config:
      stage: validate
      script: |
        if [ -s generated-config.yml ]; then
          echo "Child pipeline configuration found."
        else
          echo "No child pipeline configuration found, skipping child pipeline trigger."
          rm -f generated-config.yml
          touch skip-trigger  # Indicate to skip the trigger.
        fi
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - generated-config.yml
          - skip-trigger
      needs:
        - generate-config
      tags:
        - aws
        - prd
    
    child-pipeline:
  stage: apply-tf
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: generated-config.yml
        job: generate-config
  needs:
    - validate-generated-config
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "branch"'
      exists:
        - generated-config.yml
      changes: []
    - when: always

